# What is the square size image for android device?

Tags: android

In ImageView tag, what will be the value of hight in dp for the fully squre size of image if width is equal with total width of device(match parent)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in xml, this should be done at runtime. You can calculate the height and width of the device as below:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float heightDP = dm.heightPixels / dm.density;
float widthDP = dm.widthPixels / dm.density;
```

Now you can use the calculated width to create your square image.

Comment: Not understand properly

Comment: The dp is different from device to device depending on the size, so above code will find the total width and height of device in dp, you cannot do that in xml.

Comment: Please describe im brief...thanx